# How to import an Access MDB format database to MySQL (utf8_general_ci)?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, database-migration

I have seen some topics about this issue but none of the free solutions works with `utf8_general_ci`. When we have arabic words in files we need `utf8_general_ci`, for example.

1 - I have tried "MySQL WorkBench" but I didn't see any option to change destination table collation, it's the default one (`latin1_swedish_ci`). So arabic words are like this > `äÇåíÏ`

2 - The same story with MS Access. I have used it's "export to ODBC" feature and didn't see any option to change destination table collation, so words are like this `????`.

3- I Have tried this known tool, [bullzip access to mysql migrate](http://www.bullzip.com/download.php) but unfortunately it crashes at the beginning of migrating way because my .mdb file is more than 1 GB. Maybe there is tool for breaking mdb files into 5 or more parts ??

4 - Unfortunately the trial version of ESF Database Migration Toolkit adds char "T" at the beginning of all text fields and I can't pay 219$ for it .

Does anyone know of a free solution for this problem?

Comment: Can't comment on collation issues, but some questions : 

1. Firstly, you say the size of Access DB is 1GB. Is it compacted ?  Which version of Access ? (Caution : Take a backup before you try compacting etc).

2. Does the structure of the Access DB, lend itself to, export certain tables to smaller MDB files, export them using the tool you mention, to MySql and put them all together back in MySql ?

Comment: Thank You , solved . I have changed destination database default collation  and tried again with access export .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exporting a table to an ODBC data source, Access issues a `CREATE TABLE` statement with just the table name, column names, and column types. Therefore the character set and collation of the table will be whatever the default is for that database.

For MySQL, if the default character set for the database is `latin1` then the table will be created with the `latin1` character set. Then, when Access tries to `INSERT` Unicode characters into it they will be replaced with `?` characters in the MySQL table.

To have the table created with the `utf8` character set you can change the default character set for the database using

```sql
ALTER DATABASE `databasename` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

and then export the table from Access to MySQL.

If you are unable to change the default character set for the database then another option would be to

- create a temporary MySQL database that uses the `utf8` character set,
- export the table from Access into the temporary database, and then
- copy/move the table from the temporary database to the main database.

Comment: Yes Thank you as i said before problem solved this way .